# 2 rows stopping select query running

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this query in Oracle SQL;

```
SELECT 
       ImportRef.GL_SL_LINK_ID, ImportRef.GL_SL_LINK_TABLE, Combos.Segment5
FROM GL_IMPORT_REFERENCES ImportRef
JOIN GL.GL_JE_LINES GLLines
     ON GLLines.JE_HEADER_ID = ImportRef.JE_HEADER_ID 
     AND GLLines.JE_LINE_NUM = ImportRef.JE_LINE_NUM
JOIN GL.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS Combos
     ON Combos.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GLLines.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
JOIN XLA.XLA_AE_LINES XLAL
     ON ImportRef.GL_SL_LINK_ID = XLAL.GL_SL_LINK_ID
     AND ImportRef.GL_SL_LINK_TABLE = XLAL.GL_SL_LINK_TABLE
WHERE
     Combos.Segment1 = '310'
     AND GLLines.PERIOD_NAME IN ('10-13')
     AND ImportRef.GL_SL_LINK_ID != 352258267
     AND ImportRef.GL_SL_LINK_ID != 248391353
ORDER BY GL_SL_LINK_ID;
```

It runs in a few seconds and returns 44000 rows.

If I remove the;

```
     AND ImportRef.GL_SL_LINK_ID != 352258267
     AND ImportRef.GL_SL_LINK_ID != 248391353
```

It gets stuck and takes so long to run I have to give up. Looking at these rows in the table I can see nothing special or unusual about them. Any ideas why 2 seeming random rows could have such an impact on a query?

Replying to comments;

I was running the query initially via OPENQUERY in SQL Server it was returning rows up to these and then getting 'stuck' as a test I just excluded the next record and suddenly it worked.

There is an index on XLA_AE_LINES XLAL as;

on GL_SL_LINK_ID & GL_SL_LINK_TABLE

In response to Simon Krenger;

Fast Query;

```
Operation               Object Name         Rows    Bytes   Cost                                 SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS               27 K        1410564                                 SORT ORDER BY                               27 K    1 M 1410564                              
    NESTED LOOPS                            27 K    1 M 1410078                              
      NESTED LOOPS                          22 K    1 M 117603                               
        NESTED LOOPS                            8 K 317 K   64956                                
          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   GL.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS     7 K 119 K   349                              
            INDEX RANGE SCAN        GL.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS_N1  7 K     23                               
          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   GL.GL_JE_LINES          1   23  10                               
            INDEX RANGE SCAN        GL.GL_JE_LINES_N1       19      3                                
        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GL.GL_IMPORT_REFERENCES     3   63  8                                
          INDEX RANGE SCAN      GL.GL_IMPORT_REFERENCES_N1  23      3                                
      PARTITION LIST ALL                        1   14  57       
        INDEX RANGE SCAN        XLA.XLA_AE_LINES_N4     1   14  57
```

Slow Query;

Operation               Object Name         Rows    Bytes   Cost

```
SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=ALL_ROWS                74 K        2630601                                 
  SORT ORDER BY                             74 K    5 M 2630601                                 
    HASH JOIN                               74 K    5 M 2629290                                 
      NESTED LOOPS                                               
        NESTED LOOPS                            59 K    3 M 117602                                   
          NESTED LOOPS                          8 K 317 K   64956                                
            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GL.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS     7 K 119 K   349                                  
              INDEX RANGE SCAN      GL.GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS_N1  7 K     23                                   
            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GL.GL_JE_LINES          1   23      10                                   
              INDEX RANGE SCAN      GL.GL_JE_LINES_N1       19          3                                
          INDEX RANGE SCAN      GL.GL_IMPORT_REFERENCES_N1  23          3                                
        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GL.GL_IMPORT_REFERENCES 7   147     8                                
      PARTITION LIST ALL                        355 M   4G  1999069                         
        INDEX FULL SCAN                 XLA.XLA_AE_LINES_N4     355 M   4G  1999069
```

The big difference appears to be the switch from a RANGE SCAN to a FULL SCAN at the end I can see why that would slow it down but not sure why it would change like that, any ideas?

Comment: Out of the 44,000 rows how did you identify these two rows as the problem rows?

Comment: Show us your database schema. GL_SL_LINK_ID is the primary key or index?

Comment: On ething that i can think of is that there are many, mnay lines in XLA_AE_LINES  for those ID's. Why are you joing that table anyway, i don;t see it coming back in any restrictions or in your actual select?

Comment: I checked those ids and both only return one record. There is more to the actual query that I have written I just cut it down to the minimum to highlight my issue.

Comment: Please provide the execution plans for both the fast and the slow query. There you should see what is going on.

Comment: By "runs in a few seconds" you probably mean "returns the first x rows in a few seconds" (not all 44,000).  What happens when you add a first_rows hint? select /*+ first_rows */ ...  I'm also assuming you aren't pulling the "fast" query results from cache

Comment: tbone - No it actually returns all 44000 records in about 5 seconds. I don't know what the "fast" query result is